# Sending file to Spring Boot REST using Axios

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post, multipartform-data, axios

I am trying to send a csv file to my java spring boot backend. The code to send my file is below:

```
    var url = 'http://localhost:3001/UploadFile';
    var file = this.state.file;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    axios.post(url, formData, { 
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } 
    });
```

And the code to accept my file from Spring Boot:

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/UploadFile")
    @ResponseBody
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    }
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting an error saying that the 'Current request is not a multipart request'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not sufficient to specify content-type in frontend you need to do it in controller as well.
You should tell to spring controller what it should **consume** and also it would be nice to set RequestMethod as **POST** like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/UploadFile")
@ResponseBody
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data") {

}
```